# Remote desktop gives me a black screen

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect remotely with remote desktop from my windows machine to my ubuntu 20 machine but I get only a black screen

First I did (as I wrote in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473713/unit-xrdp-service-could-not-be-found))

```
>sudo systemctl status xrdp

Unit xrdp.service could not be found
```

So I started from 0 and did

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

and then

```
 sudo systemctl status xrdp
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-06-29 11:19:02 JST; 17s ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
   Main PID: 1953879 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 28577)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─1953879 /usr/sbin/xrdp

 6月 29 11:19:01 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953878]: (1953878)(139627163875136)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
 6月 29 11:19:01 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953878]: (1953878)(139627163875136)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
 6月 29 11:19:01 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953878]: (1953878)(139627163875136)[INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
 6月 29 11:19:01 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953878]: (1953878)(139627163875136)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
 6月 29 11:19:01 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
 6月 29 11:19:02 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
 6月 29 11:19:03 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953879]: (1953879)(139627163875136)[INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 1953879
 6月 29 11:19:03 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953879]: (1953879)(139627163875136)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
 6月 29 11:19:03 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953879]: (1953879)(139627163875136)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
 6月 29 11:19:03 my-Zephyrus-Ubuntu xrdp[1953879]: (1953879)(139627163875136)[INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
```

then

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3389 proto tcp
```

With that, I open remote desktop from my windows computer and I entered the hostname, etc

However now I have a remote window alright but entirely black.

What could be failing here and how to correct it?

Comment: the output of systemctl status xrdp is fine, xrdp is running. What desktop environment are you running - I've only ever had success with xfce with xrdp

Comment: @John - yet, you haven't posted an answer, what's the point of that comment?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. How do I find from the terminal what desktop environment the remote is running?

Comment: what desktop environment do you have

Comment: My ubuntu remote uses  ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: Googling, it seems that GNOME does not support xrdp and VNC is the only option :(  What happens if I install xfce in my ubuntu machine that is already using GNOME? how does that impact it?

Comment: See [this link](https://www.hiroom2.com/ubuntu-2004-xrdp-gnome-en/).

Comment: @harrymc It is a bit hard to follow but I checked and the environment variables are set. I dont know what xorg means but this is what I do and get a black screen

Comment: Install xrdp (sudo apt install xrdp)

Enable xrdp (sudo systemctl enable xrdp)

Start the xrdp service (must be started each time Guest is started): sudo systemctl start xrdp      .....  Works every time for me:  Windows 10 / 11 Host, Ubuntu 20 and 22 and Kali 2022 and up target machines.